# Adding values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, addition, raw-input

I would like to know how can I, using a `raw_input` command, pick out the values of two user chosen keys to add together?

What I have attempted is:

```
dict = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three" : 3}

Total = Sum(v for v in dict.values() if raw_input1 and raw_input2 in dict)
```

I did borrow that line from another thread but can't figure out how to shape it the way I need to.
All the above achieves is the sum of everything in the dictionary instead of the 2 the user picks.

Comment: Where did you declare `raw_input1` and `raw_input2`?

Comment: Sorry, was saving space so I didn't write that bit out. Figured people might have guessed by Raw_1 and Raw_2. I'll be clearer next time.

Comment: I appreciate that you want to keep your code example as minimal as you can. At the same time, it must be complete. Don't leave anything for others to guess.

Comment: Please give your expression `if a and b in x` a second thought. It does not, what you think it does. Also, please refrain from naming a dictionary `dict`. You shadow a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: @Piinthesky. 
Right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three" : 3}
total = dict[raw_input1] + dict[raw_input2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making this much more difficult than necessary. I suggest writing the steps out in words, then translating the words into Python. For example:

1. Get the first key from the user
2. Get the second key from the user
3. Get the first value from the dictionary
4. Get the second value from the dictionary
5. Add the two values together
6. Print the result

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Black90 When the site allows it, please accept the answer which you find the most helpful.

Comment: Is that your way of telling me not to thank people individually or just letting me know how the forum works?

Comment: Just telling you the expectations we have in this community. Written thanks are great, too! (p.s. Some of our members get upset when this is called a "forum." I think the preferred classification is "Q&A site".)